# Mysql 'statement level' trigger ... you can do it with tow tricks

Tags: mysql, triggers

I searched many times to find any trick or workaround to make a "statement level" triggers in MySQL like Oracle's one but I didn't found . so I came up with this trick and it works for me hope it can helps anyone

See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say we want to insert multiple rows and we want to do something for one time but we cannot avoid "FOR EACH ROW" in MySQL trigger

```
`insert to table1 (sname,age) VALUES ('mariam',5),('jojo',3),('ahmed',29)`
```

- First create a table `statementidstable` with two columns (`ID`,`statementid`)
- Second you have to prepare a uniqe ID for your statement with your software
- lets say its '123456'.

  change your statement to

  `INSERT INTO table1 (sname,age,uniqueid) VALUES ('mariam',5,123456),('jojo',3,123456),('ahmed',29,123456)`

  ```
      CREATE TRIGGER
      table1_after_insert
      AFTER INSERT
      ON
      table1
      FOR EACH ROW
      BEGIN
           DECLARE isfired tinyint(1);
           SELECT COUNT(statementid) INTO isfired from statementidstable where statementid=NEW.uniqeid LIMIT 1;
           IF isfired = 0 THEN
               '''DO WHAT YOU WANT HERE because this is the first time for this statement id
               '''then insert the statementid to statementidstable
               INSERT INTO statementidstable (statementid) VALUES (NEW.uniqeid)
           ELSE
               '''Nothing will happen becaue you already have the statement id in statementidstable 
           END IF;
       END;
  ```

  then delete the statementid from statementidstable after you are finished (handle this with your software)

** Another trick you can do it with no need for a statementid and also your trigger can fire once after inserting first row only or once after inserting last row only or both of them

- in this trick you have to prepare your statement like this

  ```
    `insert to table1 (sname,age,rowid) VALUES ('mariam',5,1),('jojo',3,0),('dodo',3,0),('ahmed',29,-1)`
  ```

first row have rowid=1 (not like any other row) makes your trigger knows that it will fire something once after inserting first row.

last row have rowid=-1 (not like any other row) makes your trigger knows that it will fire something once after inserting last row.

Other rows have rowid=0 or any other value not in (1,-1)

```
        CREATE TRIGGER
        table1_after_insert
        AFTER INSERT
        ON
        table1
        FOR EACH ROW
        BEGIN
             IF rowid = 1 THEN
                 '''DO WHAT YOU WANT HERE after inserting first row only
             ELSEIF rowid = -1
                 '''DO WHAT YOU WANT HERE after inserting last row only
             ELSE
                 '''NOTHING WILL HAPPEN
             END IF;
         END;
```

- every trick has it's own benifit ... and note that the first trick can handle 'insert statement' and 'update statement'
- I am still working on 'delete statement'